# apt ignore ssl errors?

Tags: repository

I'm getting an error connecting apt to a repo that previously worked.

Investigation shows that the repo's ssl cert expired a few weeks ago.

Is there a way to ignore ssl errors, while only using apt?

Comment: Most https repos are also available using plain http. Indeed this exact problem (cert management) the reason MOST Ubuntu and Debian mirrors don't use https. Each deb package is signed, and you can easily verify the signatures (apt does so automatically without bothering you) so you can be sure your packages are clean, complete, and untampered over plain old http.

Comment: If you are talking about some third-party deb repository: Test if you can connect to the source using an ordinary web browser using both https and http. If http works, edit your source. If http fails, contact the repository maintainer.